# Where is the terminal window in ubuntu 16.04 desktop?

Tags: gui

I installed the minimal Ubuntu desktop on 16.04 LTS.  The GUI came up just fine, but I can't find a terminal window.  Also, how do you logout/shut down the system?

Where is it or how do I install it?  Thank you.

Comment: CTRL-ALT-F1 -  `sudo shutdown -P now`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem !!

### the terminal window can open be `CTRL` + `ALT` + `T`

logout / shutdown can be found at right top corner from monitor/shutdown logo drop-down

---

in other cases you maybe have that issue because you are running a minimal version
hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to what constitutes a "*minimal Ubuntu desktop on 16.04 LTS*". With the regular install the terminal window can be activated by at least two methods. One being, press `ctl-alt-t`.  The other pressing the application icon that should be on the top left of your screen and then entering the text: "*terminal*" in the field with "`search your computer`".